# I have issues with file_pointer>>string_var; can someone please clarify?

Tags: file, c++11, fstream

I am working on C++ FILES concept. In the following program I am trying to understand how to read and write into files works.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    fstream myfile;
    string str1;
    myfile.open("H:/input_file.txt");
    myfile<<"test1 writing files"<<" ";
    myfile>>str1;
    cout<<str1<<endl;
    myfile<<"test2 append writing files"<<" ";
    myfile>>str1;
    cout<<str1<<endl;
    myfile.close();

    return 0;

}
```

I Expected the file to contain :"test1 writing files test2 overwriting files". But why the file has only: "test1 writing files". Also I cannot have any output(the value of str1) on the console. I have poor understanding of the concepts operator>> , and any buffers involved with FILE I/O. Can someone give me the clear understanding.

Comment: Read documentation of [`operator >>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt). Compile with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`). Use the debugger (`gdb`) to run your code step by step. Don't forget to [flush](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/flush). *Fix-my-code* questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In your example, you should move "cursor position" to start for read from file:

```
...
myfile << "test1 writing files" << " ";
myfile.seekg(0);
...
```

2)  The code below (your code) will reads one word in std::string

```
myfile >> str1;
```

for this reason, in your example, you should use cycle:

```
...
string tmp;
while(myfile >> tmp)
  str1.append(tmp);
...
```

Comment: adding   myfile.seekg(0); would overwrite. I actually want to append

Comment: Also I cant get even one word into str1 and console. i.e I cant even get  "test1" on the console

Comment: It would be right before reading

Comment: after opening file, you should check that it is opened

Comment: cout << myfile.is_open() << endl; //if 1 than all ok

Comment: if the file is not opened how do you think "test1 writing files" is written into the file. I think there is no problem  in opening a file.